# Laravel Routing with pagination and restful controllers

Tags: routes, pagination, laravel

I am in a similar boat with a lot of other people...coming from Codeigniter to Laravel.

I'm performing a search of a database, and pulling in the results correctly., and even have the pagination working correctly. (It only shows 30 at a time and displays the links down bottom for the rest of the results)

You start on a parts-search view, which is being called by a get function in the controller. I have a post function in the controller that is pulling the results. (URL would be parts-search still, but is pulling the post function)

The problem is, when you select page 6 (URI being parts-search?page=6), it gets routed back to the function that pulls in the first parts-search page.

I want to say I have to do something like this:

`Route::any('parts-search?page=(:any)')`

but I don't know how to maintain the same search variables, or if the query has to be run each time.

These are my files:

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('home');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});

Route::get('parts-search', 'home@parts_search');

Route::post('parts-search', 'home@parts_search');
```

**home.php (Controller)**

```
public $restful = true;

public function get_index()
{
    return View::make('home');
}

public function get_parts_search()
{
    return View::make('part-search');
}

public function post_parts_search()
{
    if (Input::get('part_search'))
    {
        $term = Input::get('part_search');
        $parts = Part::where('part', 'LIKE',  $term.'%')
            ->order_by('part', 'asc')
            ->paginate(30);

        return View::make('results')
        ->with('parts', $parts)
        ->with('term', $term);
    }
    else
    {
        return View::make('part-search')
            ->with('error', '<h1>Please enter a search term</h1>');
    }

}
```

Both direct answers and a place for me to learn would greatly be appreciated...and any course correction as this is day 3 of Laravel for me. Thanks!

So I've confirmed it is definitely a routing issue, but haven't the faintess clue as to where to begin. And I have been asking the Google gods all day to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is *generally* why you do search queries as GET requests, so that the search keywords appear in the URI. Most applications do it this way, even Stack Overflow.

To maintain the query string when you want to change pages you [can append to the pagination links](http://laravel.com/docs/views/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links).

Comment: Ok so now my problem is that the pagination creates links with ?, but I cannot parse them out unless they are /. If I try setting Route::get('results?(:any?)', function($term = NULL) I still get a 404